# External hard drive that gets its power supply from the PC

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, power, mac-mini

I need an external drive to connect to my MacMini.  I've been using an 80gb 2.5 drive in an enclosure and it's fine, but now I need a 1.5TB drive.

Unfortunately all the 1.5TB drives I found need a separate power supply.  I'd like it to be able to feed its power off the USB drive (just like my 80gb drive does).

Does something like that exists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only 2.5 inch hard drives can be powered off the USB bus. The current largest is a 640gb (http://www.gearlog.com/2009/09/toshiba_intros_industrys_large.php#).

3.5 inch drives require more power and cannot be powered by the USB bus because of thier power requirements. These drives are available up to 2Tb.

Comment: not soon, but now. I have a sweet WD 640GB drive in my laptop bag. :D

Comment: Cool, I had not seen one for sale yet, just announced. Good to know.

Comment: Reluctantly accepted.

Comment: I know, it would be awesome if 3.5 drives could be bus powered for external drives, but unfortunantly, that is not the case. :(

Comment: Just wait. It wasn't that long ago that I was bemoaning the 340GB limit on my 2.5" drive. Hell, I still remember getting a 2GB drive back in High School and thinking "I'll never fill this!"

Comment: I've seen external 3.5" drives that claim to work without external power, once they're spun up. In theory you would unplug the wall transformer after the drive is running. Probably not very useful in practice.

Comment: @Nelson: Yah I would consider that very unreliable.  Maybe future computer interfaces will allow enough power to support 3.5inch drives, but not for now.

Answer (score 0):

Western Digital is shipping 1TB SATA 2.5: drives WD Scorpio Blue 5400RPM. Great if your enclosure is SATA.  750GB as well.  No 1.5TB as yet

http://www.westerndigital.com/en/products/products.asp?driveid=685

Comment: -1. eSATA != USB. Mac Mini has no eSATA interface.

Comment: Should have been 1 TB SATA(corrected) and enclosure dictates the interface. There are a number of 2.5 enclosures with USB that would power the 1 TB drive noted.  Assume AngryHacker can grab this 1TB 2.5 drive and add an enclosure to get what was requested.  I beliebve MAcally makes at least one PHR-S250CC